# MariaDB 10 SQL-Dump Error: mysqldump: unknown option '--no-tablespaces'

Tags: mariadb, mysqldump

I'm using a MariaDB 10 installed on a QNAP TS-435XEU from QNAP-AppCenter. It is shown as V1.0.4.32.

My ERP-Software is designed to work with a MySQL-Database and I've already passed some issues, e. g. enabling lower case table names by adding lower_case_table_names=1 in my.cnf and other.

Everything was fine, but now the ERP-Software want's to make a database-backup which fails. I do not need this backup, as I do the backup from PHPMyAdmin myself, but the ERP-Software cannot be upgraded unless the (built-in) database-backup has completed successfully.

So I'm forced to deal with the following Error:
mysqldump: unknown option '--no-tablespaces'

From my (beginner) point of view, it seems, that the ERP-Software request the Database to do a dump with that option and the Database tells, that this option is unknown.

As there is no way to change the SQL-Request from ERP-Software, the only way seems to configure the database to ignore all commands and options wich are unknown and do not stop the backup.

I've read about a 'force' command and wonder, if this command can be added to configuration-file, too.

Does anyone have an idea, what to do in this situation? Again, everything was fine until now, I were able to work with the ERP-System, no errors at all. But now I cannot work anymore unless I solve this backup-issue and perform the program-update I cannot skip unfortunately.

Best regards,

Lucas

---

@Rick James: QNAP App Maria DB shows:
SQL Server: MariaDB 10.5.8

@Rick James: lower_case_table_names was a necessary option to use, as the (Windows-)ERP-Program queried some tables with Uppercase Characters

@danblack: Thanks for checking the availability of the --no-tablespaces option in Version 10.5.8! The mysqldump comes from Windows-ERP-Application 'Sage50' and unfortunately there is no way to change anything (because it is 'built in' and no accessible script)

Comment: Which version of MariaDB 10?  10.7.1 Changelog says "Removed CREATE/DROP TABLESPACE and related commands"

Comment: Changing `lower_case_table_names` sounds dangerous.  It is rather important for Windows versus Linux.

Comment: The `--no-tablespaces` is still there in the [mariadb code](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/11.0/client/mysqldump.c#L261). Its also in the MySQL-8.0 code. So one big question is where is `mysqldump` from. A work around would be a `mysqldump` script that strips the `--no-tablespaces` out of the command before calling the real `mysqldump`

Comment: The version is 10.5.8 looking at the qpkg of 1.0.4.32 for your device, and its `mysqldump` still has [--no-tablespaces](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/mariadb-10.5.8/client/mysqldump.c#L230).

Comment: `force` could be added to a `[mysqldump]` section of a configuration file, but it doesn't bypass argument errors, only SQL errors. I understand `mysqldump` is called from Sage50, but is it also provided *by* Sage50, so they have a mysqldump that doesn't work with their own software? Can you trick the software into thinking a backup exists (a backup looking file where it expects)?

Comment: Sage50 Support told me, there is no way to skip or trick the backup. For my understanding Sage50 (which lets the user choose between their own database 'SageDB 5.7' and MySQL 5.7) calls mysqldump. The error mysqldump: unknown option '--no-tablespaces' occurs only on MariaDB10, not when using the SageDB. Support told me, that my own Database (MariaDB10) obviously doesn't support --no-tablespaces, but as @danblack told, it is still there in the mariadb code. Is there a way to trace the SQL-Queries MariaDB is receiving from Sage50 for investigation?